# Separate dchpd.lease file for each subnet

Tags: isc-dhcpd

Is there a way that I can configure dhcpd to create a separate dhcpd.lease for each subnet?

**i.e:**

subnet 192.168.0.0 - \var\lib\dhcp\dhcpd.168.0.0.lease

subnet 192.168.1.0 - \var\lib\dhcp\dhcpd.168.1.0.lease

subnet 192.168.2.0 - \var\lib\dhcp\dhcpd.168.2.0.lease

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?  If your solution involves parsing lease files you should re-think it.

Comment: At this moment all of the leases from devices in multiple subnets are stored in one lease file (\var\lib\dhcp\dhcpd.lease). I want to configure the dhcp server so that it creates a seperate lease for each subnet. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do that.

The leases file is an internal database of dhcpd. There is no reason for you to look at it.

If you want to know which host is at which IP address, then look at [dynamic DNS](/questions/305151/local-hostname-resolution-with-bind-and-custom-domain/305187#305187); that's what it's for.

If you want to know which IP addresses are active, then... also look at dynamic DNS, and try using `dig axfr <your.domain>`?

If you want to clean it up, then don't -- dhcpd will do that all by itself from time to time.

If you want to do something else, then clarify what exactly it is you want to do. I'm sure there is a better solution to do that which does not require separate lease files.